# StatSVN generated XML is slightly out of date

Tags: svn, xml, diff

There are no [StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/) questions on superuser, but why not start? ;-)

Here's my problem... I generate a log from subversion with:

```
svn log -v --xml > log.xml
```

The latest revision that shows up in that file is **5311**.

Next, I generate a StatSVN xml file with this single command (broken into multiple lines here):

```
java -jar statsvn.jar \
-include "**/*.c:**/*.h:**/*.cpp:**/*.hpp:**/*.pl:**/*.sh:Changelog" \ 
-xml -cache-dir ./cache -output-dir ./xml log.xml .
```

The above command includes only .c, .h, .cpp, .hpp, .pl files and also the file "Changelog".

It works, except that the last revision that is found in resulting "repo-statistics.xml" is **5309** (2 revisions prior to the current one). I have made changes to .h and .cpp files in **5310** and **5311** so they should show up in `"repo-statistics.xml"`. Do you have an idea why they don't?

I've been consistently running into this problem of repo-statistics.xml lagging 1-2 revisions behind the current one.